# It's not showing the DNS why it is called reverse IP lookup?

Tags: ip-address, dns

I have searched a lot but I didn't get the reason that even after giving the IP address it never shows the DNS. If it doesn't give the DNS then why it is said to be reverse IP lookup?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not showing the DNS'? Your question could do with a bit more explanation what exactly it is you're asking. Maybe giving an example could help?

Answer (score 5):

*Reverse DNS* is a term for looking up the DNS PTR record for an IP address - essentially resolving it 'backwards' to a host name (in contrast to 'forward' resolving a host name to an IP address using the A record).

While this *should* be supported everywhere, it often *isn't* due to a lack of setup or to security concerns. You'll need to set up your DNS correctly (off-topic here) or contact your network admin if you think that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse of security reasons . Orginastion security policies are framed insuch a way that while creating A record in public dns or authoritative dns server only forward lookup is created reverses lookup  is not configured .

In forward lookup => domain name is mapped with ip address

Reverse lookup=> ip address  mapped with domain name..